# create objects in a loop and enter it to a function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following r code:

```r
df1 <- haven::read_sav(here::here("data", "filename.sav"))
df2 <- haven::read_sav(here::here("data", "otherfilename.sav"))
df3 <- haven::read_sav(here::here("data", "anotherone.sav"))

result <- stackDf(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

which I want to facilitate:

```r
filenames <- c("filename.sav",
         "otherfilename.sav",
         "anotherone.sav")

for (filename in filenames){
  # Don't know what to do here
  file <- haven::read_sav(here::here("data", filename))
}

result <- stackDf(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

But I don't know how to get the `file`-object (within the loop) to the call of my function `stackDf()`. Can somebody please help me? Yes, there might be more than just three files in reality, because of that I'd rather like to automize it.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
file <- lapply(filename, 
               function(f) haven::read_sav(here::here("data", f)))
do.call("stackDF", file)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map(filename, ~ haven::read_sav(here::here("data", f))) %>%
         reduce(stackDF)
```